# Use OData in Azure Function .NET 6

Tags: c#, azure-functions, odata

I've installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` nuget package in order to bring OData query in Azure function

I have the following `Run` method

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Select | AllowedQueryOptions.Filter | AllowedQueryOptions.Top)]
[FunctionName("myfunc")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ODataQueryOptions<MyModel> oDataQuery)
{
    var items = await _dbService.ListAsync();
    return new OkObjectResult(oDataQuery.ApplyTo(items.AsQueryable()));
}
```

and I have `FunctionStartup`

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(MyAPI.MyStartup))]
namespace MyAPI
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class MyStartup: FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>();
            ...

            builder.Services.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), opts =>
            {
                opts.Documents = new[] {
                        ...
                };

                opts.ConfigureSwaggerGen = opts =>
                {
                    ...
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I run application, I got exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot bind parameter 'oDataQuery' to type ODataQueryOptions`1. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).'

But I don't know how to register OData in Startup.

How to add support for odata in azure function (.net 6) ?

Comment: maybe using dotnet-isolated you'll have more flexibility (not sure tbh)

Comment: @Thomas then there may be other package to use OData in Azure Functions .net 6 ?

Comment: https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/main/AzureFuncDemo might help. Just for your reference.

Comment: @SamXu good sample.

Comment: I think if you've defined a `Startup` class for configuring the container your azure functions cannot be `static`. You'll define your azure function like a typical Asp.net controller.

Comment: Have you resolved it ? I have a same issue